Accessing an env var whose name comes from an interpolated string
I have the following:
for VAR in "GB" "IE" "DE" "CA" "NY"
do
    echo $(STRIPE_$VAR)
done

I'm trying to print the 5 env vars SRIPE_GB, STRIPE_IE etc...
This returns
zsh: command not found: STRIPE_GB

zsh: command not found: STRIPE_IE

zsh: command not found: STRIPE_DE

zsh: command not found: STRIPE_CA

zsh: command not found: STRIPE_NY

I've tried
for VAR in "GB" "IE" "DE" "CA" "NY"
do
    echo "$(STRIPE_$VAR)"
done

and a list of other varieties but can't seem to get it to recognise $(STRIPE_$VAR) as $STRIPE_GB.
Any help is appreciated

[tag:zsh] is not same than [rag:bash]!

@F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub aren't the errors identical..?

But in this case yes: echo $(cmd) try to execute cmd and echo his result.

I didn't actually know there were syntax differences, thanks for the comment

I don't get what you want to achieve: Inside the loop, you are constructing strings like STRIPE_GB, then you try to run this string as a command, and pass the stdout of this command as the first parameter to echo. The error message just says that zsh does not find such a command. What happens if you execute STRIPE_GB manually on the command line?

I'm not a zsh user but you'll have to do something like this:
#!/bin/zsh

STRIPE_GB=foo
STRIPE_IE=bar

for var in GB IE
do
    ref=STRIPE_$var
    echo "${(P)ref}"
done

foo
bar



But it's more confortable to use an associative array:
#!/bin/zsh

declare -A STRIPE=(
    [GB]=foo
    [IE]=bar
)

for var in GB IE
do
    echo "$STRIPE[$var]"
done

foo
bar



Associative arrays arne't exportable, so that's not an option to replace actual environment variables.

Now that you say it, OP did specify that those are env vars indeed

In Zsh, indirect variable expansion is performed with ${(P)varname}:
So here is how your code could look like:
#!/usr/bin/env zsh

STRIPE_GB='in gb'
STRIPE_IE='in ie'
STRIPE_DE='in de'
STRIPE_CA='in ca'
STRIPE_NY='in ny'

for country_code in "GB" "IE" "DE" "CA" "NY"
do
    ind=STRIPE_$country_code
    printf 'Stripe country %s value: %s\n' "${country_code}" "${(P)ind}"
done


Bash and ZSH are not the same thing. In case of Bash, what happens inside ${...} is not a recursive shell expansion. It is quite significantly different. The workaround is to synthesize the whole variable name first and then use it.
# Setting the variables:
for var in GB IE DE CA NY; do
  declare -n stripe_ref="STRIPE_${var}"
  stripe_ref="This is the value of ${!stripe_ref}."
done

# Reading the variables:
for var in GB IE DE CA NY; do
  stripe_name="STRIPE_${var}"
  declare -n stripe_ref="STRIPE_${var}"
  printf ' First option: %s = %s\n' "$stripe_name" "${!stripe_name}"
  printf 'Second option: %s = %s\n' "${!stripe_ref}" "$stripe_ref"
done


I thought they behaved identically under the hood.. thanks for the rundown

This is because you try to execute STRIPE_xx in a subshell since you type it in () paranthesis. The subshell treats STRIPE_xx string as if it was a shell command.
Remove the () and try interpolating like this: echo "$STRIPE_$VAR" or echo "${STRIPE}_${VAR}".
